# Composer outdated command export to a file such as excel or csv?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm running `composer outdated` and I have a toooon of outdated packages, over 300, and I'd like to export this to an excel sheet or something like that. Does anyone have any idea how I could do this?

I ran `composer outdated` and it spat out A LOT of information in the terminal, with over 300 packages that need updating. I'd like to find a way to put this into an excel sheet or csv easily.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that CSV isn't an option, however JSON is via `composer outdated --format=json`, and from that you could build a quick CSV. Also, I just tried taking the normal output, copied it and used the Excel import Wizard with a space delimited. The description column gets split up, but can be rejoined. Or, you can take the output and paste it into a tool with multi-line edit support like Sublime and just draw some commas in, and quote text appropriately.

Comment: If it's a linux system, you can output it to a file with `composer outdated > outdated.txt` and then you can edit that file the way you need to

Comment: @aynber It works on Windows too.